Use of Type V platform for regular Air Cargo Transportation with MB-1 chain set
As background, military air transportation is regulated by Technical Orders, Field Manuals, etc. In this case, TO 13C7-1-5 is the one that regulates Platform Delivery System, used for cargo airdrop. To this objective, type V platforms are used due to its special characteristics. However, it is never specified if it can be used as well for cargo transportation without airdropping it. Air cargo transportation is usually done with 463L pallets aka P1P.
Is there any regulation that mentions how to use type V platforms for cargo air transportation instead of 463L pallets? Are these type V platforms only allowed to be used for airdrop?
Last question but not the least: Is there any limitation on the use of MB-1 or MB-2 chain sets with type V platforms if they are to be used for air transport, besides the proper limitation on connection of both systems?
This is a very specific and rare question. I guess Air Force members can clarify this end. Thanks.
